# Git hook post-receive não efetua checkout no WIndows

Tags: git

Estou utilizando o git para fazer um **deploy automático**.

São dois computadores com windows 7 em uma rede local. Um deles seria um servidor e o outro seria o meu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Eu criei um repositório BARE no meu servidor e um outro repositório no servidor que conterá os arquivos php que serão acessados pelo usuário

Eu consigo efetuar o push da minha maquina de desenvolvimento para repositório BARE no servidor.

No servidor eu verifiquei que o repositório BARE está sendo atualizado pois eu clonei ele para uma outra pasta do servidor e está normal e atualizado

Contudo após efetuar esse mesmo push é apresentado o seguinte **erro**

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 281 bytes | 281.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: Invalid path 'C:/xampp': No such file or directory
To //nrspdt214406/var/repo/planejamento.tecnico.git
   dd1adcf..ea5b4c8  master -> master
```

E com isso os arquivos que estão no BARE não vão para o meu repositório que será de acesso publico.

Se eu executar o checkout -f através do git bash no repositório BARE o repositório publico é atualizado.

**O post-receive está da seguinte forma:**

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE='c:/xampp/htdocs/planejamento.tecnico' git checkout -f
```

Comment: Ele está reclamando que a pasta não existe. Você roda sobre MingW?

Comment: A pasta existe sim, eu estou suspeitando que pode ser algum caractere de escape, mas não consigo identificar. E sobre o MingW, desculpe a minha ignorância, não sei informar se está rodando sobre isso ou não.

Comment: O MingW é uma ferramenta para rodar coisas Unix no Windows. Já existe há um tempão. Hoje também tem outras alternativas, e versões mais modernas até mesmo vem com algum `bash` embutido (ou com download da loja). Falei do MingW porque nele não há `c:/xampp`, mas sim `/c/xampp`. Nesse caso, `c:/xampp` seria uma referência à pasta `c:` dentro do repositório _bare_, e dentro dessa pasta ainda haveria a subpasta `xampp`. Pode ser que ele esteja pegando referência relativa, e não absoluta. Pode ser, mas precisaria ter certeza, experimentar